# Copy some records in the same table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to copy some records in the same table for new user (75) with incrementing id in  `mySQL`.
ID is not an autoincrement.

content of table is :

```
 ID       USER      col1    col2  
 67       60        toto1
 68       60        toto2           
 69       60        toto3
 70       60        toto4
 71       60        toto5
 72       60        toto6
 81       60        toto7
 82       60        toto8
```

what i expect in the same table :

```
 ID       USER      col1    col2  
 67       60        toto1
 68       60        toto2           
 69       60        toto3
 70       60        toto4
 71       60        toto5
 72       60        toto6
 81       60        toto7
 82       60        toto8
 83       75        toto1
 84       75        toto2                       
 85       75        toto3
 86       75        toto4
 87       75        toto5
 88       75        toto6
 89       75        toto7
 90       75        toto8
```

Comment: Is the ID column `autoincrement`?

Comment: NO ID is primary key INTEREGR NOT NULL

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the rule behind that transformation?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea would be to insert-select from the same table.

If the `id` is defined as auto_increment, just leave it out of the query and let MySQL do its thing:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (user, col1)
SELECT 75, col1
FROM   mytable
WHERE  user = 60
```

If it isn't, you can manually increment it:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (id, user, col1)
SELECT id + 8, 75, col1
FROM   mytable
WHERE  user = 60
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ID` is `AUTOINCREMENT`;

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT
75,col1, col2
FROM table
WHERE USER = 60
```